# Offline mode for UWP application(framework that implements this feature)

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

My UWP application needs to perform following tasks

1. let user access application when offline(without showing
   disconnected    error)
2. store user data entered locally
3. update when there is network available

I want to achieve it using sync framework like an entity framework where I do not need to implement everything manually.

I have heard of Microsoft sync Framework but I am not sure of it's compatibility with windows 10 applications

Thanks

Comment: I need a framework that can implement caching , local storage and updating all by itself. Is there any such product or framework or service or a plug-in?

Comment: To be more specific here is a scenario: when user opens application in offline mode, the user should be able to feed in data in the application without "not connected" message. Once the application is in network, data should automatically update to the server

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach for this scenario is to use the [Azure Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync/) and their Offline sync capabilities.

Comment: But I do not want to use Azure Mobile Apps. And is there any framework or a plugin or a service that does all things required? I don't want to implement everything manually.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to use Azure Mobile Apps?

Comment: because of two reasons , first is that for using azure offline service you need license and I do not want to buy the subscription. Second, the project I am working on does not allows the use of Azure(limitation from client side) . Also I think when we create UWP application there should not be a dependency like this. I know the entire thing can be coded but I need a framework or a single utility that does it all

Comment: There is no dependency of Azure at all in UWP. But you asked for a framework, and one of them is Azure Mobile Apps.